# How to escape the white space in folder name of a file?

Tags: java, file

Consider the `source_folder_name` as  `D:\Desktop\test util\config sql`
In the code given below the white space in the folder name i.e  `test util`  and  `config sql`  is not handled properly.
I need to escape those white spaces.

```
 public class SqlToTblCoverter {

  private File source_folder = null;

 public SqlToTblCoverter(String source_folder_name) {
    source_folder = new File(source_folder_name);
   }

  public void check() {
    System.out.println("Source folder"+ source_folder);
   }
 }
 public class test{
     public static void main(String args[]){
     Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter Input Folder Path");
                String input=in.next();


                    SqlToTblCoverter config_migrator = new 
    SqlToTblCoverter(input);
    }
  }
```

On executing the above code the value of source_folder comes is

> Source folder: D:\Desktop\test

whereas expected is

> Source folder: D:\Desktop\test util\config sql

Please help me out

Comment: There's nothing in your posted code that would mishandle a filename with spaces. Please edit your question to include the code that calls the `SqlToTblCoverter()` constructor, and show where the filename string originally comes from.

Comment: @Kenster I have edited the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation of `Scanner` you will see:

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern,
>   which by default matches whitespace.

So the problem is your scanner. If you use the newlines as delimiter, everything should work as expected.